# Python: user input exception handling with Str

Tags: python, string, exception

```
     while True:
        first_name = input('Please enter your first name:\n')
        last_name = input('Please enter your last name:\n')
        try:
             firstn = str(first_name)
             lastn = str(last_name)
        except ValueError:

            print('did not enter str')
            continue
        else:
            return firstn
            return lastn
```

I'm trying to use exception handling with my code. I want to check whether or not the user has inputed the correct string value for first and last name. users cannot input numbers for their first and last names. my code seems to ignore the Value error if I use numbers for usernames.

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: You need to actually perform the validation in order to check if the users have entered number as their names, probably with a regular expression: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the understanding of what you code does. When you do

```
first_name = input('Please enter your first name:\n')
```

then `first_name` is already a string representing the exact user input. So you writing

```
firstn = str(first_name)
```

has actually no real effect, except copying `first_name`. The string might be something like `"12345"` but is still a valid string. What you want is probably to check if the string only contains alphabetic characters, which can be achieved by calling `.isalpha()`:

```
if not first_name.isalpha():
    raise ValueError
```

Not directly related to your question, but also worth noting:

```
return firstn
return lastn
```

will also not have the desired effect, since only the first return will be executed, resulting in only `firstn` to be returned. You probably want:

```
return firstn, lastn
```